# Get Vertical Scroll position on Ipad with jquery

Tags: jquery, ipad, scroll, window, overflow

I have a site, which is much wider, than the Ipad screen.

I am looking for a way, to get the vertical scroll position from the window and change it by jquery.

Lets say the current pos is 400px. I want to be able, to scroll to 700px.

I already tried  `window.pageXOffset` and muc more, but got no usable result.

Comment: `window.scrollWidth` for the available scrolling area, and `window.scrollLeft` for the current scroll position.

Comment: @adeneo This returns an 'undefined'

Comment: [**scrollWidth**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollWidth) and [**scrollLeft**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollLeft) surely exists, so then you're doing something else wrong.